# In Vue how do I link to a component containing user-specific data?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I took a Udemy course in building a Vue application with Firebase. The application consist of a signup and login page. Once you are logged in, you will be taken to a Google Map which shows your location. If you click on the location marker you will be taken to a profile page containing your personal information.

The thing is, I don't want to access this information from a marker. I want to access it from a normal link in the Navbar. 
Can you show me what I need to change to make this possible?

The method used for the marker looks like this

```
    methods: {
        renderMap(){
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: this.lat , lng: this.lng },
                zoom: 6,
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 3,
                streetViewControl: false
            })
            db.collection('users').get().then(users => {
                users.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    if(data.geolocation){
                        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: {
                            lat: data.geolocation.lat,
                            lng: data.geolocation.lng
                            },
                            map
                        })
                        marker.addListener('click', () => {
                            this.$router.push({name: 'ViewProfile', params: { id: doc.id }})
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

In my Navbar I have written the link like this (which does not work):

```
<li v-if="!user"><router-link :to="{ name: 'ViewProfile' }">Login</router-link></li>
```

I tried doing this (but it did not work either):

```
 <li v-if="user"><router-link :to="{ name: 'ViewProfile',params:{ id: doc.id }}">Profile</router-link></li>
```

Comment: You want to show all available users in the navbar or you want to go to the profile page from the logged user?

Comment: The issue might lay in the variable passed `doc.id ` since it is being pushed as a param from the forEach loop.

Comment: As the code is now, when a person is logged in they see a map with a marker showing their location. When they click on that marker they are brought to a profile page where their personal information is stored. This is done with an addListener: `this.$router.push({name: 'ViewProfile', params: { id: doc.id }})` I want to change this so that instead of clicking a marker, I want a normal link in the navbar called "Profile" that the user can click on.

Comment: With the code in your question you will create a marker (and a link) for **EACH** user in the users collection. How do you identify the specific user for which you want to generate a link in the nav bar?